# Conectar PHP 8.1 con SQL SERVER 2019

Tags: sql, sql-server, php8

tengo un sistema el cual lo realice inicialmente con PHP y MYSQL

He realizado la migración hacia SQL SERVER, y estoy tratando de realizar la configuración, ya descargue e instale los dll y los referencie en XAMMP en php.ini, sin embargo me arroja el siguiente error al momento de iniciar sesión

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi archivo de conexión

```
<?php

class Cconexion{

    function ConexionBD(){

        $host='localhost';
        $dbname='sistema_encuestasv1';
        $username='DESKTOP-SIMP7PV\tulio';
        $pasword ='';
        $puerto=1433;

        $con = new PDO ("sqlsrv:Server=$host,$puerto;Database=$dbname",$username,$pasword);
            echo "Se conectó correctamen a la base de datos";
        
        
    }

}

?>
```

y este es mi archivo **validacion.php**

```
<?php   

session_start();

$id_usuario = $_POST['id_usuario'];
echo $id_usuario;
$clave  = $_POST['clave'];
echo $clave;
include("conexion.php");

$query = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id_usuario = '$id_usuario' AND clave = '$clave'";
    

    $resultado = $con->query($query);

    
    if ($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {


        if ($row['id_tipo_usuario'] == '1') {
            $_SESSION['id_usuario'] = $row['id_usuario'];
            $_SESSION['u_usuario'] = $row['nombres'];
            header("Location: administrador/index.php");
        } else {
            $_SESSION['id_usuario'] = $row['id_usuario'];
            $_SESSION['u_usuario'] = $row['nombres'];
            header("Location: usuario/index.php");
        }
        
        if ($row['id_tipo_usuario'] == '3') {
            $_SESSION['id_usuario'] = $row['id_usuario'];
            $_SESSION['u_usuario'] = $row['nombres'];
            header("Location: usuario_vista/index.php");
        }

    } else {
        header("Location: index.php");
    }

    if (!$query) {
        printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($conn));
        exit();
    }
    

 ?>
```

y estan son mis tablas de la base posterior la migración

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si alguien me puede ayudar ya que esto de la migracion para mi es totalmente nuevo y no se si me paso por alto algo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se de donde sacais esos ejemplos o tutoriales, ya van dos preguntas similares en pocos dias con el mismo problema.

Tienes dos soluciones a simple vista:

1. Editar el archivo **conexion.php** y dejarlo así, sin clase ni función:

```
$host='localhost';
$dbname='sistema_encuestasv1';
$username='DESKTOP-SIMP7PV\tulio';
$pasword ='';
$puerto=1433;

$con = new PDO ("sqlsrv:Server=$host,$puerto;Database=$dbname",$username,$pasword);
echo "Se conectó correctamen a la base de datos";
```

de este modo, al hacer su include, estas haciendo global la variable $con y la puedes usar directamente tal como ya estás intentando.

2. O bien, agregar un `return $con;` al final de la función **ConexionBD** del archivo **conexion.php** para que, después de incluir ese archivo **conexion.php** con un include en otro archivo, llamar debidamente a la clase y a la función de este modo:

```
include("conexion.php");
$claseConexion = new Cconexion();
$con = $claseConexion->ConexionBD();
// resto del código a continuación...
```

Comment: Muy bien, he realizado lo que me dices pero ahora me aparece este error ```Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: No se puede establecer una conexión ya que el equipo de destino denegó expresamente dicha conexión``` ya he abierto los puertos TCPIP en SQL y ahora si no se que pueda pasar

Comment: @MarcoTulio Entiendo tu fustración, después de arreglar esto, pero eso es un error nuevo, por lo tanto una pregunta nueva.  Si vamos encadenando errores en las respuestas o en las propias preguntas, éstas pierden el sentido y luego todo es un lio y no ayuda a los demás que vengan a buscar la solución de la pregunta original.  Si mi respuesta te ha servido para solucionar el problema inicial puedes [aceptarla](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200).  Si a raíz de eso tienes un nuevo problema, debes formular una nueva pregunta.

Comment: No tengo la solución a todos los errores ni es cómo funciona este sitio.  Como orientación, por lo que yo se, puedes probar de realizar un `telnet localhost 1433` desde tu propia máquina en un terminal y comprobar si obtienes una respuesta o se queda colgado.  Si obtienes una respuesta entonces los puertos estan bien y el fallo puede estar en los datos suministrados.  Si se queda colgado o aparece un mensaje de error entonces o bien el puerto 1433 no esta a la escucha o bien el servidor sqlserver no funciona bien. Pero como decia, mejor preguntalo para obtener mejores respuestas.

Comment: muchas gracias colega, he podido solucionar el inconveniente modificando el archivo de conexión y reinstalando mi SQL SERVER, ya que no había habilitado el MIXED MODE, lo volvi a reinstalar y habilite este junto con el usuario sa, comparto como quedo mi archivo conexion ```<?php

$serverName = "DESKTOP-SIMP7PV"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"sistema_encuestasv1", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"123456789");
$con = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
?>``` con eso la conexion se realiza perfecto, sin embargo tengo dudas y hare otra pregunta

Comment: Perfecto, me alegro que lo hayas solucionado :-)  Saludos!